# GPUImage WhiteBlanceFilter with Chaining

Tags: ios, c, gpuimage

I am attempting to chain (via plist) several filters together to get specific looks.  I took the demo app (filter showcase) and added a WhiteBalanceFilter to the chain.  The effect is a pure yellow screen.  If I do this via code I get expected results...but with chaining it is just yellow.  Here's the piece I added to the plist:

```
    
    FilterName
    GPUImageWhiteBalanceFilter
    Attributes
    
    setTemperature:
    float(5000.00)
```

Any thoughts?  I thought maybe "float" was the wrong type but all indications are that is the right type.

Comment: In GPUIMageFilterPipeline.m there is a translation of string from the plist to floats, points, etc.  For some reason a white balance of 3000 was being translated to a crazy number once it was changed to a float (something like 1011110 or higher).  I added an if statement to check for int (they setTemp takes an int) as well as added it to the parsingRegex and all is golden now.

Comment: Yeah, the GPUImageFilterPipeline is something that someone else contributed, and quite frankly I've never touched it myself. I don't know many people that use it over just defining filter chains in code, and it has a tendency to break every now and then.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Brad.  Much appreciated.